# Why MEF has [ImportMany] and not just [Import]

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, mef

I just hunted down an problem in my mef application; problem was, that I had an `[Import]` instead of `[ImportMany]` in my `IEnumerable<IFoo>` property. I started to wonder why. MEF sees that the injection target is a "collection" and could determine that collection is needed instead of a single element. At least Ninject works this way.

Does anyone have insight why `[ImportMany]` is required? Only reason I can think of is that one might want to `[Export(typeof(IEnumerable<IBar>)] public IEnumerable<Bar> { get; }` but is this really the reason for this design? I bet I'm not the only one who has been debugging this kind of error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not the same ;)

`[Import]` indicates that you want to import *a single thing* according to a contract. In MEF, a contract is just a string, and when you import a type (like `IEnumerable<IBar>`), you're really importing according to a contract which is just the *name* of that type.

In MEF, *cardinality* is very important, so when you state that you wish to import a *single* instance of something that fits the stated contract, there can only be a *single* source. If multiple exports are found, an exception is thrown because of cardinality mismatch.

The `[Import]` functionality doesn't contain special logic to handle `IEnumerable<T>`, so from its perspective, it's *just a contract like everything else.*

The `[ImportMany]` attribute, however, exists especially to bridge that gap. It accepts zero to any number of exports for the stated contract. This means that instead of having a *single* export of `IEnumerable<IBar>` you can have *many* exports of `IBar` scattered across multiple assemblies, and there's never going to be a cardinality mismatch.

In the end it's a design philosphy. MEF could have had special, built-in knowledge about `IEnumerable<T>`. Autofac (and apparently Ninject) does that and call it a [Relationship Type](http://nblumhardt.com/2010/01/the-relationship-zoo/).

However, special-casing like that implies that somewhere the implementing code violates the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), which again can lead to [POLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) violations, so in this case I tend towards taking side with the MEF designers. Going for a more explicit API may decrease discoverability, but may be a bit safer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In my case the annoying thing was that `compositionContainer.ComposeParts(this);` did not throw an exception, instead my ImportMany import elsewhere was one dependency short. Only hint was log output about rejected export. This is of course by design, and luckily I found mefx tool to diagnose problems. This kind of error can be quite hard to track if the object graph is big.

Answer (score 2):

To simplify the above answer slightly:

- `[Import]` will throw an exception if there is more than one matching export.
- `[ImportMany]` will load more than one matching export without throwing an error.

If I have an IDataAccessLayer that I want to import, there should only ever be ONE export available - I'm never going to be writing to 2 databases simultaneously so i use `[Import]` to ensure that only one will exist.

If I want to load up many different BusinessObjects, I will use `[ImportMany]` because I want lots of different types of BusinessObjects.